# How do I maintain current user in GAE after post/redirect for get?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

I have a form users submit which is posted /FormHandler and handled. The FormHandler class then redirects to a UpdateFormHandler which refreshes the form fields with the updated fields so users can see their current form fields and make changes as necessary. The problem is each user can have multiple forms and the GAE datastore users the current logged in user to lock down editing other user forms. How can I send the GET back while maintaining the current logged in user. `users.get_current_user()` on the GET function returns none.

Comment: Are you using django?  You can have multiple forms on one page.  And, you should be using POST instead of GET.

Comment: I am. Sorry, I'm pretty new to this. So we have FormA. User submits FormA which is handled by `post(self)` in `class FormHandler`. This should then send another POST through say `post(self)` in `class FormRefreshHandler`. So when they submit the form again, it will follow the same loop. Also having issue of refresh causing resubmit of the form, which is the reason for the GET

Comment: You should only need one form handler.  That form handler sets new values into the template `context` and displays the same template, with the new values, after the POST.

Comment: Thank you, will try those changes now. What about users refreshing the page and resubmitting the POST data? The forms are used to create lesson plans which have customizable numbers of questions. There are checkboxes to delete and add question indices, and refreshing will keep deleting or adding questions.

Comment: Pass the checkbox values back and forth in the context.